# How can I controll what external web site accesses my web service?

Tags: php, web-services, security

****I'm trying to find out how the "simplest" form of identification can be achieve in order for my partners website to access my web service to retrieve information.****

I want to make sure that only my partner has access to retrieve this information. There is no sensitive data as the data will be shown on my partners website. But I don't want other websites taking advantage of my web service and retrieve data without having access to do so.

I know I can get the IP address using the [HttpRequest object](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php&ei=fRR8T-epJvLE4gT8wf2pDg&usg=AFQjCNGqlmFygLjTp017KHbOWrb2T3cKKQ), then do a reverse lookup. But not all websites has dedicated ip address and a ISP may use the same IP Address for multiple websites.

I can't see how passing unique identifiers as parameter in the URL can help, because "anyone" can catch that data and use it themselves. But I will use it as an added check.

So the only "secure" way I come up with, is identifying the website accessing my website, then control this against a list on my server.

I would appreciate feedback on what methods would be "most secure".

Comment: You should look into how web API's work...

Comment: Any suggestions where to look? I've already developed web service for my mobile app. So I am familiar with handling HTTP requests returning JSON data. But now I'm developing a new web service for another target group.

Comment: Are users accessing only their own content or can they access any content once they have access?

Comment: The only content they currently can retrieve, are a list of stores selling their brand. They will not be able to retrieve store lists for any other brand.

Comment: @Steven I was specifically talking about the way API calls are authorized using public and private keys. *Many* sites follow a similar method (Google, Twitter, GitHub, etc). This will allow only people with registered keys to make API calls against your web service.

Comment: @cillosis Thanks mate. I think I found a useful website that will get me started: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication. Can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common practice amongst web services to use public/private keys to authenticate API requests. A few example sites that use them: [Google](https://developers.google.com/+/api/), Twitter, [EventBrite](https://www.eventbrite.com/api/key), [Last.FM](http://www.last.fm/api/account), GitHub, etc.

These work by having a public or consumer key which is known to everyone. Then each user is given a private or secret key to allow authentication. The cool thing about using this, is since you know exactly who is making the request you have the ability to track activity and potentially throttle number of requests if abused.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this great article on how to design secure REST API: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Answer (score 2):

The most secure method is to use SSL channel and ask for authentication. If authentication passes then you can give back to client some sort of session key(which can be randomly generated string) and check it on every request.

If your service don't allow to use SSL, then you can try just adding simple username/password authentication for your partners, but in this case if someone intercept your communication they can access your service with same credentials.

Other way is using signatures on every request. For example you can use GPG for this purpose. Your server is holding public keys of all your partners. When partner wants to make query to your server he just signs his request with his private key and upon receiving you will be able to securely verify that this request was sent by particular partner and it's 100% not forged.

**Edit**

For GPG you need to install PECL module called [**gnupg**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php). Here is class from our framework that utilize GPG functionality.

```
class GPG
{

    /**
     * Encrypt given data to one or more recipients
     * 
     * @param string $string
     * @param string|array $encryptKeyID
     * @param bollean $armour
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encrypt($string, $encryptKeyID, $armour = true){
        $gpg = new Crypt_GPG();

        if(is_array($encryptKeyID)){
            foreach($encryptKeyID as $keyId){
                $gpg->addEncryptKey($keyId);
            }
        }
        else{
            $gpg->addEncryptKey($encryptKeyID);
        }

        return $gpg->encrypt($string, $armour);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt given data
     *  
     * @param string $string
     * @param string $keyPassword
     * @param string $keyID
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decrypt($string, $keyID, $keyPassword = null){
        $gpg = new Crypt_GPG();

        $gpg->addDecryptKey($keyID, $keyPassword);

        return $gpg->decrypt($string);
    }

    /**
     * Sign given string
     * 
     * @param string $string
     * @param string $keyID
     * @param string $keyPassword
     * @param boolean $mode
     * @param boolean $armor
     * @return string
     */
    public static function sign($string, $keyID, $keyPassword = null, $mode = null, $armor = true){
        $gpg = new Crypt_GPG();

        if($mode === null){
            $mode = Crypt_GPG::SIGN_MODE_CLEAR;
        }

        $gpg->addSignKey($keyID, $keyPassword);

        return $gpg->sign($string, $mode);
    }

    /**
     * Verify signature of given message
     * 
     * @param string $string
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function verify($string){
        $gpg = new Crypt_GPG();
        $signatures = $gpg->verify($string);

        if ($signatures[0]->isValid()) {
            return true;
        } 
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt and sign given string to one or more recipients
     * 
     * @param string $string
     * @param string|array $encryptKeyID
     * @param string $signkeyID
     * @param string $signkeyPassword
     * @param boolean $mode
     * @param boolean $armor
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encryptAndSign($string, $encryptKeyID, $signkeyID, $signkeyPassword = null, $mode = null, $armor = true){
        $gpg = new Crypt_GPG();

        if($mode === null){
            $mode = Crypt_GPG::SIGN_MODE_CLEAR;
        }

        $gpg->addSignKey($signkeyID, $signkeyPassword);
        if(is_array($encryptKeyID)){
            foreach($encryptKeyID as $keyId){
                $gpg->addEncryptKey($keyId);
            }
        }
        else{
            $gpg->addEncryptKey($encryptKeyID);
        }

        return $gpg->encryptAndSign($string, $armor);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt and verify given string
     * 
     * @param string $string
     * @param string $keyID
     * @param string $keyPassword
     * @return array|false
     */
    public static function decryptAndVerify($string, $keyID, $keyPassword = null){
        $gpg = new Crypt_GPG();

        $gpg->addDecryptKey($keyID, $keyPassword);

        $result = $gpg->decryptAndVerify($string);

        if(empty($result['data']) and empty($result['signatures'])){
            return false;
        }

        if(isset($result['signatures'][0])){
            $result['signature'] = $result['signatures'][0]->isValid();
            unset($result['signatures']);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. GPG sounds interesting. I see that PHP has something called `GnuPG` (not able to access php.org just now) - but this probably requires that this service is enabled in php.ini? If so, my partners ISP may not enable it. Do you know of any tutorials on GPG?

Comment: Here I posted GPG class from our framework that is easy to use and integrate in your code.

Comment: Yeah, and by the way you because it is PECL module it don't require that ISP enable it, you can include it in your code.